# how to set on click method for text inside dialog

Tags: java, android, onclick, textview, android-dialog

I have dialog contain TextView. Inside the TextView I have number so i want to set onClick method for the TextView and I want to use call method to call the number inside the TextView

Inside the dialog xml file i set the textview as below

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#2d76ba" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:onClick="no1"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and here is my dialog

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop); // pop is my dialog xml
dialog.setTitle("Phone Call");
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setText(values[0]); /// I'm calling the number from array

public void no1(View v) 
    {
        Intent dial = new Intent();
        dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
        dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+values[0]));
        startActivity(dial);
    }
```

but the onClick method (no1) is wrong it says "void is an invalid type for the variable no1"

how can i correct the method to work inside the dialog ?
I tried to make it outside the dialog but when i click the textview the logcat says

> 11-04 13:39:48.666: E/AndroidRuntime(26249): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method no1(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.TextView with id 'text1'

so it looks like the function is not available

Comment: You can't create a void method inside your Dialog.

Comment: As below code just implement OnClickListener to you TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.pop); // pop is my dialog xml
dialog.setTitle("Phone Call");
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text1);
text.setText(values[0]); 
text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
        public void onClick(View view) 
         {
          Intent dial = new Intent();
          dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
          dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+Global.values[0]));
          startActivity(dial);

         }
    });
```

Comment: It could be the solution but you should suggest what was the mistake and the possible solution!

Comment: op should also remove `android:onClick` from the xml